# VB to C# Optional Parameters

Tags: c#, vb.net

Ive been searching for a solution to this but have not yet gotten a solid answer.  I have VB code that i need to convert into c#.  Here is the VB code.  I have tried different solutions but none of them seem to work. Here is the definition of the function

```
Protected Sub LoadData(ByVal ProcedureName As String, ByVal NumOuts As Long, ByRef Label1 As Label, Optional ByRef Label2 As Label = Nothing, Optional ByRef Label3 As Label = Nothing)

    Dim ConnStr As String

    ConnStr = "Data Source=H50;Initial Catalog=" + Me.DatabaseName.Text + ";Integrated Security=True"
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConnStr).....
```

And here is one of the many functions that call upon this

```
Protected Sub LoadtblStaffContactsBtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LoadtblStaffContactsBtn.Click
    LoadData("Load_tblStaffContacts", 2, Me.tblStaffContacts_Label1, Me.tblStaffContacts_Label2)
    Me.LoadtblStudentBtn.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far too

Comment: [Named and Optional Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

Comment: It works the same, except you don't need the optional keyword.

Comment: http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Just a suggestion: You should ByRef/Byval an optional collection of Labels and check its .Count property, instead adding a lot of parameters.

Comment: Another suggestion... why not use `Overloads`??  After a brief Google, I believe it works the same way in C# as it does in VB.

Comment: @Grim: C# has optional parameters - why wouldn't you convert VB optional parameters to C# optional parameters?  (except for the "ByRef" - as mentioned by Guffa, you can't have C# 'ref' optional parameters, but this was likely a mistake in the original VB code anyway).

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: I'm not going to start off another VB vs. C# debate!  However, I was merely pointing out that Overloading is another method, and one that I prefer.  Obviously if the OP has hundreds of calls to that routine, it's best to do as you suggest!

Comment: @Grim: I'm also not interested in a VB vs C# debate - just wanted to point out that VB and C# are on the same page regarding optional parameters (or overloaded methods as an alternative).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing optional parameters by reference, this is not possible in C#.

Unless you actually change the label references in the method (which seems extremely unlikely), those parameters shouldn't have been passed by reference in the first place.

Just pass the paremeters by value as normal, and make them optional by specifying a value:

```
protected void LoadData(string ProcedureName, long NumOuts, Label Label1, Label Label2 = null, Label Label3 = null) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use default parameter e.g. with null

```
private void TestFunc(string s1, string s2 = null)
{
}
```

Call this way:

```
TestFunc("s1");
```

or

```
TestFunc("s1", "s2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward. In C# use null in place of VB.NET Nothing, however you can use any value for a default.

Simply make sure they are trailing parameters, and assign a value just like you would a local variable.

```
public void foo(int a, string b, string c = "something", object t = null)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Protected void LoadData(out string ProcedureName, out long NumOuts, ref label Label1,          ref label Label1 = null, ref label Label3 = null){
    string Connstr;
    ConnStr = // Connection String;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connstr).......
}
```

The below is for handling the button click event.

```
Button1.Click += (object sender, System.EventArgs e)=>
{
    LoadData("Load_tblStaffContacts", 2, this.tblStaffContacts_Label1, this.tblStaffContacts_Label2);
 this.LoadtblStudentBtn.Enabled = true;
}
```